sum up the values of duplicate rows using pandas
I have a df
id    val1     val2
 1     1.1      2.2
 1     1.1      2.2
 2     2.1      5.5
 3     8.8      6.2
 4     1.1      2.2
 4     8.8      6.2
 3     8.8      6.2
 1     1.5      2.8
 5     8.8      6.2

I want to sum up values in val1 and val2 for the duplicate ID
Final df:
id    val1     val2
 1     3.7      6.12
 2     2.1      5.5
 3     16.16    12.4
 4     9.9      8.4
 5     8.8      6.2


out = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).sum()
